# Is there a way to a string identifier and a related quantity in postgresql in an array?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to figure out how to store an array of {identifier: quantity} in PostgreSQL

where identifier is a string and quantity is a number. I suppose I could simply use a string[][] matrix but I'd rather be able to strongly type the data in a way like string[]int[].

Thanks

Comment: Most likely an array is a bad concept. Why not a table with columns `identifier` and `quantity`?

Comment: @klin so my current situation is I want to keep track of a shopping cart per row. I'm new to relational as I just game from mongo so this is what I was going for

Comment: @klin would I just have a table of items with identifier and quantity and reference those rows from the cart database?

Comment: Yes, you need an additional column to identify a cart the properties belong to. This is the most natural approach in SQL. However, if the quantities once inserted are immutable (you don't have to modify them) you could consider a jsonb (not jsonb[]!) column in the cart table as an alternative.

Comment: @DucksEatTurtles "*…and reference those rows from the cart database?*" - no, the other way round. Each row in the identifier-quantity table needs to reference one cart (i.e. the one it belongs to), so that you can have multiple entries in a cart. You'd do that by adding a third column to the items table, and have `cart_id` and `identifier` as the primary keys. This allows you to fetch the quantity of a given item in a given cart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resolution from the comments on the original post was to have two tables, one for cart and one for cart-items and map the items from cart-items to cart.